# Unrelated JQuery functions effecting eachother

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn how to use JQuery and I'm running into problems. Triggering one function is setting off the effects of other unrelated functions and I don't know why. When I click the box2 element why do the effects of box1 fire as well?

When a "p" element is clicked, box1 should expand to 100% width. When "box2" is clicked it should expand to 400px height. The problem is that when I click box2 , box1 is also changing.

NOTE: this is only an exercise, so no need to worry about doing things perfectly here. Just trying to figure out this quirk. Thanks!

## Here's my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   *{ padding:0px; margin:0px;}
   p { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;   color:#fff;}
   #box1 { background-color:#003366; height:60px; width:350px; padding:15px;}
   #box2 { background-color:red; height:60px; width:350px; padding:15px;}
   .center{text-align:center;}
   .red{color:red;}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
<!-----------------function p onclick--------------->
  $("p").click(function()
  {
    $("#box1").animate({ width: '100%'});
     
    $("h1,h2,p").addClass("center");
   
  });

<!-----------------function box2 onclick--------------->
  $("#box2").click(function()
    {
      $("#box2").animate({ height: '400px'});
    });

});<!--end document.ready JQUERY-->

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="box1"><p>Test It</p></div>
    <h1>Just some words here.</h1>
    <div id="box2"><p>Test It</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a p element, inside a #box2 element. Both the p element and the #box2 element have click events. When you click on p element, the click event on #box2 will also fire. Therefore your jquery functions ARE related. make your first function more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a click handler assigned to all paragraphs, and there's a paragraph in both boxes:

```
$("p").click(function()
```

Change that to:

```
$("#box1").click(function()
```

or

```
$("#box1").find('p').click(function()
```

Comment: Oh, heh. Easy fix, though I'm surprised....I wouldn't think clicking box 2 would trigger the effect assigned to "p". (and I was careful not to hit the "p" inside box2), but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't click just `box2`, you click the paragraph `p` which is inside `box2`, that's why it triggers also the first handler.

You could change

```
$("p").click(function()
```

to

```
$("p").not('#box2 p').click(function()
```

to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `box1` click handler is updating all `h1`, `h2`, and `p` elements. Add some context if you only want children of `box1`.

```
$("h1,h2,p", "#box1").addClass("center");
```

Also, as others have mentioned, your first click handler is assigned to all `p` elements.